# Spring R2DBC DatabaseClient execute custom delete query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, sql-delete, spring-data-r2dbc

Hi im trying to delete user by his id from a table in Postgres database.
Im using Spring and R2DBC and trying to use `DatabaseClient.execute("sqlCommand")` for my custom delete query:

```
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomSqlService {
    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;


  public Mono<Void> deleteWithCustomSql(String sql) {
            databaseClient.execute(sql)
            return Mono.empty();
    }
```

Where `sql` is `"DELETE FROM user_table WHERE user_id = 1;"`

Method in the Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("postgres/")
@Timed
public class PostgresController {

// omitted code


   @DeleteMapping(path = "/delete_user/{userId}")
    public Mono<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId)  {
       return customSqlService.deleteWithCustomSql("DELETE FROM user_table WHERE user_id = " + userId);
    }
```

But when I test it, command is not working. When i debug i can see there's `MonoOnResumeError` in the result from `.execute()`.

I have other methods that perform `insert` and `select` statements in the same fashion and they work well.

The test I have for it:

```
 @Test
    void shouldDeleteDataFromTable() {
        User user = User.builder()
                .userId(1L)
                .sessionId(2L)
                .timestamp(10L)
                .build();

        webTestClient
                .post()
                .uri("/postgres/save_user")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(Mono.just(user), User.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()

     webTestClient
             .delete()
             .uri("/postgres/delete_user/1")
             .exchange()
             .expectStatus()
             .isOk();
      
        userRepository.findAll().take(1).as(StepVerifier::create)
                .expectNextCount(0)
                .verifyComplete();
```

How to correctly use `databaseClient.execute()` for custom delete query in PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are using the latest R2dbc 1.0 and Spring Data R2dbc(managed by Spring Boot 3.0).

Your method `deleteWithCustomSql` does not work. There is no subscription on the `databaseCLient.exectue`, the sql is never be executed and return a result.

Try to change to the following, move sql here, and use `bind` to bind a parameter to sql.

```java
 public Mono<Long> deleteByUserId(Long userId) {
     return databaseClient.sql("DELETE FROM user_table WHERE user_id = :userId")
         .bind("userId", userId)
         .fetch()
         .rowsUpdated();
}
```

In the controller, changed to the following.

```java
@DeleteMapping(path = "/users/{userId}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity> deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId)  {
    return customSqlService.deleteByUserId(userId)
        .map(deleted -> {
            if(deleted>0) return noContent().build();
            else return notFound().build();
         });
}
```

Check my [working example of `delete` operations](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java#L129-L140), which demonstrates how to bind a parameter in sql, it is based on the latest Spring Data R2dbc/Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already solve this problem when I change returning type of Mono<Void> to Mono<Integer> but I don't get why is that. Can You provide a link to some docs about subscription to operators like databaseClient.execute and why do I need to return some type and not the Mono<Void> ?

Comment: When client to the API endpoint, it will create a subscription, but your `dbClient.execute` is never subscribed by the client, read the [Reactive Streams](https://www.reactive-streams.org/) spec to under the publisher API.

Comment: Returning a `Mono<Void>` is so easy, you can `flatMap`, `then`, etc. method to convert or shift to a new publisher if you know well the APIs of [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/).